# Arial font in signature line for outlook is changed to times new romance when inserted

Tags: fonts, outlook, xml-signature, outlook-web-addins

I'm using Office.js to insert signature while composing the message. My problem is that, on first inserting it changes Font and Font size to wrong value and if I insert it again or insert some other signature than it inserts it correctly.
In this particular example all settings in Outlook are set to Arial 11 and signature that I want to insert is also Arial 11.

```
function mergeAndInsertHtmlTemplate(_html, _json, isSignature, templateId, onDoneCallback, directMerge) {
        getMailBody(function (_htmlBody) {
            if (!_htmlBody.startsWith("<template>")) {
                var t = document.createElement("template");
                t.innerHTML = _htmlBody;
                _htmlBody = t.outerHTML;
            }

            // template html merged with data
            var _mergedHtml = mergeHtmlAndJson(_html, _json);
            if (isSignature) {
                var mergedSignature = mergeHtmlSignature(_htmlBody, _mergedHtml);
                if (mergedSignature.succeeded) {
                    updateMailBody(mergedSignature.html, function (result) {
                        factory.PrependData("");
                    });
                }
                else {
                    insertAtCursorLocation(_mergedHtml); // insert at cursor location
                }
            }
            else {
                if (Object.keys(_json).length > 0 && !directMerge) {
                    _mergedHtml = mergeMustachAndJson(_htmlBody, _json, true);
                    updateMailBody(_mergedHtml);
                }
                else {
                    _mergedHtml = mergeMustachAndJson(_html, _json);
                    insertAtCursorLocation(_mergedHtml);
                }
            }
            if (onDoneCallback) onDoneCallback();
        });
    }

function mergeHtmlSignature(mailBodyHtml, signatureHtml) {

        if (!mailBodyHtml.startsWith("<template>")) {
            var t = document.createElement("template");
            t.innerHTML = mailBodyHtml;
            mailBodyHtml = t.outerHTML;
        }

        var $mailBody = $(mailBodyHtml);
        var endComposeIndex = $mailBody.find("*").index($mailBody.find('a[name=_MailEndCompose]'));
        // $mailBody.find('[style*="_MailAutoSig"]').parent().not('div').empty(); // tryout: signature inserted twice 
        var toRemove = [];
        $mailBody.find('*[class*=iw-signature]:not(:has(a[name=_MailAutoSig]))').each(function () {
            var thisIndex = $mailBody.find("*").index($(this));
            if(endComposeIndex < 0 || thisIndex < endComposeIndex){//if ($(this).prevAll().filter("a[name=_MailEndCompose]").length == 0) {
                var parentTables = $(this).parents("table");
                toRemove.push(parentTables);
                toRemove.unshift($(this));
            }
        });

        for (var i = 0; i < toRemove.length; i++) {
            toRemove[i].remove();
        }

        $mailBody.find('[style*="_MailAutoSig"]').each(function () {
            var parentTables = $(this).parents("table");
            toRemove.push(parentTables);
            $(this).remove();
        });

        for (var i = 0; i < toRemove.length; i++) {
            toRemove[i].remove();
        }

        var _signatureLocations = $mailBody.find('a[name=_MailAutoSig]');

        if (_signatureLocations && _signatureLocations.length > 0) {
            _signatureLocations.parent().empty().html(signatureHtml);
            return { html: $mailBody[0].outerHTML, succeeded: true }
        }
        else {
            $log.warn('No signature location to insert signature. Inserting at cursor location');
            return { html: signatureHtml, succeeded: false };
        }
    }

function insertAtCursorLocation(data) {
        if (factory.BodyType === MailBody.HTML) {
            // Body is of HTML type. Specify HTML in the coercionType parameter of setSelectedDataAsync.
            Office.context.mailbox.item.body.setSelectedDataAsync(data,
                {
                    coercionType: Office.CoercionType.Html,
                    asyncContext: { var3: 1, var4: 2 }
                },
                function (asyncResult) {
                    if (asyncResult.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Failed) {
                        $log.error(asyncResult.error.message);
                    }
                });
        }
        else {
            Office.context.mailbox.item.body.setSelectedDataAsync(data,
                {
                    coercionType: Office.CoercionType.Text,
                    asyncContext: { var3: 1, var4: 2 }
                },
                function (asyncResult) {
                    if (asyncResult.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Failed) {
                        $log.error(asyncResult.error.message);
                    }
                });
        }
    }

function updateMailBody(data, callback) {
        Office.context.mailbox.item.body.setAsync(data, { coercionType: factory.BodyType }, function (result) {
            if (callback) callback(result);
        });
    }
```

This is signature that I want to insert:

```
<div>
<a name="_MailAutoSig">
    <div class="iw-signature" style="-aw-headerfooter-type: header-primary;">
        <p class="iw-signature" style="margin: 0pt;">
            <span class="iw-signature" style="font-family: Calibri; font-size: 11pt;">&nbsp;</span>
        </p>
    </div><p class="iw-signature" style="margin: 0pt 0pt 8pt; line-height: 108%; font-size: 11pt;">
        <span class="iw-signature" style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 11pt;">Kind regards,</span>
    </p><p class="iw-signature" style="margin: 0pt 0pt 8pt; line-height: 108%; font-size: 11pt;">
        <span class="iw-signature" style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 11pt;">This one is also with ARIAL 11.</span>
    </p><p class="iw-signature" style="margin: 0pt 0pt 8pt; line-height: 108%; font-size: 11pt;">
        <span class="iw-signature" style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 11pt;">Byeeeeeeeeeeee</span>
    </p>
    <div class="iw-signature" style="-aw-headerfooter-type: footer-primary;">
        <p class="iw-signature" style="margin: 0pt;">
            <span class="iw-signature" style="font-family: Calibri; font-size: 11pt;">&nbsp;</span>
        </p>
    </div>
</a>
```

I'm doing it while mail body is empty so mail body have default value and function insertAtCursorLocation(data) is called where data is signature html itself.

You can see font style and size on next images:

[signature line when first inserted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/go7XF.png)

[Signature line when inserted for second time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pyIq4.png)

Can you please suggest me what is the best approach to deal with this problem? Even it is workaround, it would mean a lot to me.

Comment: Hi Stefan,

Could you please post the code where you're actually inserting into the body? The snippet you have seems to just be retrieving the template.

I just tried this code sample in latest Outlook 2016: Office.context.mailbox.item.body.setAsync("Hello", {coercionType: "html"});

and it worked as expected. What version of Outlook are you using?

Comment: function updateMailBody(data, callback) {
            Office.context.mailbox.item.body.setAsync(data, { coercionType: 
factory.BodyType }, function (result) {
                if (callback) callback(result);
            });
        }

I'm using Version 1701, Build 7766.2076

Comment: @StefanDjordjevic I tried this out, however, I could not reproduce this issue. Can you share an example of values for mailBodyHtml and signatureHtml? And for updateMailBody, is "data" the ".html" of the output of mergeHtmlSignature?

Comment: @KwameAD I edited original post with new info. Sorry for late response I was on holiday.